SQL SELECT: restrict rows from Table1 to those having only specific rows in Table2
(A simplified example).
I have Table1 with items:
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
| 1  | car   |
| 2  | apple |
| 3  | grass |
| 4  | alien |
+----+-------+

and Table2 with colors that these items can be:
+----+------+--------+
| id | item | color  |
+----+------+--------+
| 1  | 1    | blue   |
| 2  | 1    | green  |
| 3  | 2    | red    |
| 4  | 2    | green  |
| 5  | 2    | yellow |
| 6  | 3    | green  |
| 7  | 3    | yellow |
| 8  | 4    | yellow |
| 9  | 4    | green  |
+----+------+--------+

I need to select all items (and ideally their colors, too) that can be either green or yellow, but not in any other color. I'm stuck at WHERE in SELECT Table1.id, Table1.name, Table2.color FROM (Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table1.id=Table2.item) WHERE…. Can you help me?
Ideally the result should be:
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| Table1.id | Table1.name | Table2.color  |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+
| 3         | grass       | green         |
| 3         | grass       | yellow        |
| 4         | alien       | yellow        |
| 4         | alien       | green         |
+-----------+-------------+---------------+

(Sorry if this is a duplicate question of a already answered one, but I couldn't find one here, I even have no idea what keywords to search ‍♂️)

Common WHERE NOT EXISTS.

If your school is still using SQL Server 2005, find a better one.

@Akina  Thanks, but as far as I found the syntax would be similar (identical at the beginning) but longer, than what Rodger Kong suggested. Nevertheless thanks for pointing out such solution!

@DanGuzman We have no influence on DB software used by our company's supplier.

If your company is using a Supplier that requires use of an obsolete database version, find a better one.


Calculate each item's colors.
Exclude items which colors more or less than 2.
Recalculate remained items colors with limit ('green', 'yellow').
Items which colors equals 2 are what you need.
JOIN tables to get information.

Code is here
    SELECT T1.id, T1.[name], T2.color 
    FROM 
      Table1 T1 
    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT A.item 
      FROM
      (
        SELECT id, item, color, count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY item) colors 
        FROM table2
      )A
      WHERE
        A.colors = 2
        AND A.color IN ('green', 'yellow')
      GROUP BY
        A.item
      HAVING count(*)=2
    )B
    ON 
      T1.id = B.item
    INNER JOIN table2 T2
    ON 
      T1.id = T2.item


Sorry, misunderstood, I thought the needs is items have both 'yellow' and 'green'. Items have 'yellow' or 'green' is here
SELECT T1.id, T1.name, T2.color FROM #table1 T1 
INNER JOIN #table2 T2 
ON 
  T1.id = T2. item
WHERE 
  T1.id NOT IN
  (
    SELECT item FROM #table2 WHERE color NOT IN('green', 'yellow')
  )


Great thank you, @Rodger Kong! Logic looks legit and it works on a test mini-database I have at home <3 I'll be able to test it in my work in 2 weeks, then I'll mark your answer as solution :) I see the query is rather simple, I just lacked the logic… can I ask how did you come up with that? Did you think "if this, then that, so this, and the code should look like this" or you're so advanced DBA that you think in SQL? ;D

How did you find the steps that I got the solution! :DD
